# Multilingual Site Map joomla

Tags: extensions, seo, multilingual, google

I have a multilingual Joomla 3.6.5.

My question is how can I create a sitemap for the installed languages?

I know that extensions exist for doing that, but if you don't want to use it how is this possible?

If I remember correct since J1.7 there's not a subfolder for each language, so how do you provide the correct sitemap for the languages you have in Google for example?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**
I realise that my first question wasn't clear enough.I'll Try to make it more specific.I had a JSite in old version 1.5, i create a new one in J3.6.5. In Google Webmaster Tools they were set up like

1) thedomain.com as the default language and
2) thedomain.com/en as the alternate for the english language which it was in subfolder named en

Of course they had their own sitemap.
Now in J3.6 which is multilingual i have to set up the new site maps. For the default language it's OK. I put it in the root on my server and it's working.

But for the english version there isn't an en subfolder, so how do i declare the sitemap for that version? 
GWT wants the sitemap for that version to be in http://thedomain.com/en 
Do i have to configure somehow the GWT domain for that version or do i have to do something else? That's my problem actually.

Comment: and why don't you want to use an extension?

Comment: FFrewin because OSmap for example it's not fully compatible with GWT guidelines. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need dynamic sitemap creation from inside your Joomla, then you need an extension or to develop something on your own, that will scan/crawl your site to discover urls and then generate the `sitemap.xml`. It will need also to be triggered and updated when you create new content/pages.

- **[JED: Sitemaps](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/structure-a-navigation/site-map)**

There are also other 3rd party SEO services that provide sitemap generators, or other stand-alone online sitemap generators etc. Just google about it e.g.:

- [**G:Search: xml sitemaps online**](https://www.google.gr/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=xml%20sitemaps%20online&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=UmN_WOb2Bare8gfdspvgCw)

Finally, if you don't update your content very often, you can always create a `sitemap.xml` file by hand:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
    <url> 
        <loc>http://www.example.com/page1</loc>
        <lastmod>2016-01-18</lastmod>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url> 
    <url> 
        <loc>http://www.example.com/page2</loc>
        <lastmod>2016-01-18</lastmod>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url> 
        <loc>http://www.example.com/fr/page1</loc>
        <lastmod>2016-01-18</lastmod>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url> 
        <loc>http://www.example.com/fr/page2</loc>
        <lastmod>2016-01-18</lastmod>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: I realise that my first question wasn't clear enough.I'll Try to make it more specific. See the EDITED section in the first question. Thanks FFrewin for the answers.

Comment: @Harrk: your question takes a total new direction now - although I think I am still missing clues to fully understand. I don't know where are the settings regarding the multi-lingual in GWT and haven't ever seen GWT require to have a different sitemap for each language and moreover to place this under a special subfolder. Why to create a second sitemap? Also keep in mind that this is not a SEO or Google Support Site.

Comment: FFrewin yes you're right in all of your comments. I sorted things out which was based in the way the GWT properties was set up, by someone else. I think according to my first question your answer covers the general guidelines, so should accept it as correct? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Harrk - I am glad if I have helped you. And yes you can accept it, if you think it answers your questions.